# Upload CVs file onto Jupyter web application

Tags: csv, file, download, jupyter

How to download csv file onto web application of Jupyter. The error said “Cannot save non-python file” when I tried to download the cab file from local.

The error said “Cannot save non-python file” when I tried to download the csv file from local.

Comment: Mismatch with title and text of the post in regards to 'upload' vs 'download' and  'CVS' vs. 'Cab' makes it hard to tell what you are asking here? Plus 'Jupyter web application' tells us very little. There are a lot of online versions, or seemingly online, e.g., JuptyerLite. Where and what actual version of Jupyter? I will say if it is JupyterLab then you usually drag and drop from your local system to upload to the remote system. Similarly for JupyterLab in JupyterLite except 'the remote system' is actually running in your own browser.